# Redirect www https site to non-www https cause too many redirect in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, server

I have a project in Laravel, I am using digital ocean with nginx, I try to redirect www to non-www urls but I can't, this is my nginx configuration:

**example.com**

```
 server{
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server{

   listen [::]:443 ssl;
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {

  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/website/production/public;
  index index.php index.html;

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

https://example.com //works

http://example.com -> https://example.com //works

http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com // redirects to www https, with too many redirects

https://www.example.com // too many redirects.

I want that when people visits **http://www.example.com**,**http://example.com** and **https://www.example.com** it redirects to **https://example.com**, What can I do? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `server` block contains a loop:

```
server{
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The value of `$host` is the same as the requested domain. The purpose of this block is to change the requested domain from `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

The simplest solution is to change the `return` statement and explicitly specify the final domain name:

```
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
```